# How can I get icon of Windows app in CPP?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to build an File Manager with in Win32, and I have a problem with the icons. Whenever I trying to get icon that an windows 10 app is associated with it like .png (Photos app), the icon is blank paper. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance and please answer :)

```
BOOL InitTreeViewImageLists(HWND hwndTV) {
    HIMAGELIST himl;  // handle to image list 
    HBITMAP hbmp;     // handle to bitmap 


    // Create the image list. 
    if ((himl = ImageList_Create(16,
        16,
        ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK,
        3, 0)) == NULL)
        return FALSE;


    // Add the open file, closed file, and document bitmaps.
    HICON hIcon;
    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    LPCWSTR path = L"C:\\Users\\Shalev\\Desktop\\WhatsApp.lnk";
    sfi = GetShellInfo(path);
    HICON* iconHandles = new HICON;
    hIcon = sfi.hIcon;
    cout << hIcon << endl;
    g_nOpen = sfi.iIcon;
    ImageList_AddIcon(himl, hIcon);
    sfi = GetShellInfo(L"C:\\");
    hIcon = sfi.hIcon;
    g_nClosed = sfi.iIcon;
    ImageList_AddIcon(himl, hIcon);
    sfi = GetShellInfo(L"C:\\");
    hIcon = sfi.hIcon;
    g_nDocument = sfi.iIcon;
    ImageList_AddIcon(himl, hIcon);

    // Associate the image list with the tree-view control. 
    TreeView_SetImageList(hwndTV, himl, TVSIL_NORMAL);

    return TRUE;

}

SHFILEINFO GetShellInfo(LPCWSTR path) {
    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    SecureZeroMemory(&sfi, sizeof(sfi));
    SHGetFileInfo(path, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);
    return sfi;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, your code is leaking `iconHandles`. It is allocated, but never used for anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [IShellItemImageFactory interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory), something like this:

```
...
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED); // need this somewhere when your thread begins, not for every call
...
IShellItemImageFactory* factory;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(path, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))))
{
    // the GetImage method defines a required size and multiple flags
    // with which you can specify you want the icon only or the thumbnail, etc.
    HBITMAP bmp;
    if (SUCCEEDED(factory->GetImage(SIZE{ 256, 256 }, SIIGBF_ICONONLY, &bmp)))
    {
        ... // do something with the HBITMAP
        DeleteObject(bmp);
    }
    factory->Release();
}

...
CoUninitialize(); // call this each time you successfully called CoInitializeEx
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this and update you.

Comment: There is a way to check if the app icon is successfully gathered or not? Like I can use the blank paper method but if a real file also have blank icon so it's will not work

Comment: This is a Shell API that creates images for the Shell to display, so in general, it will always get some icon back.

Comment: Oh okay. I tested it and it worked just as desired. Thank you! Btw, why my method didn't work but yours works?

Comment: Windows and icons story is 35-years old... algorithms behind IShellItemImageFactory implementation are quite complex.

Comment: Oh okay. This only works on Windows or I can use it on Linux too?

Comment: Windows API don't even exist on Linux

Comment: There is a global way of getting the icons? Away that works on multiple OS

Comment: You can definitely get icons from static files on different OSes for files with a known file format (.ico, .dll, .exe, etc.) but this is a very different question from the original one.

Comment: how can I do that? I think it will be more efficient for what I'd like to do. I want to make a remote file manager and use the icons of the client for files with different extensions.

Comment: There are things you won't be able to do out of Windows. For the rest, ask another question.